# IE7 ReportViewer Control

Tags: html, internet-explorer-7, reportviewer2008

I have a site that I built and works well for everyone in IE8/IE9, Chrome and FireFox. However, now my client is asking for this to work in IE7 as well since there machine still has IE7. I can’t figure out what is wrong with the ReportViewer Control. Any help would be appreciated.

The issue is that my report goes way outside of the set height and width; it doesn’t stay within the DIV that I have wrapped around it using jQuery

**jQuery Code**

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            var htmlwidth = $('.main').width() - 20;
            var htmlheight = $(document).height() - $('.header').height() - 45;
            $('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').wrap('<div style="overflow:auto;" />');
            $('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').parent().css(height, htmlheight);
            $('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').parent().css('width', htmlwidth);
            $('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').css('width', htmlwidth);
            $('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').css(height, htmlheight);
            $('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').parent().css('border', 'solid 1px Black');
    });
```

**Content**

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="100%"  Width="100%"
    SizeToReportContent="true" ZoomMode="Percent" AsyncRendering="false" >
</rsweb:ReportViewer>
```

**Sample Generated Block {content + jQuery Code}**

```
<div style="width:500px; overflow:auto; border:solid 1px Black;height:400px;">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="400px"  Width="500px"
        SizeToReportContent="true" ZoomMode="Percent" AsyncRendering="false" >
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks like your facing the IE7 overflow issue. You can read more about it [here](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/position_relative_overflow_ie/)

To fix your problem set the outer div to have `position: relative`

Add the following line to your jQuery:

```
$('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').parent().css(position, relative);
```

Or add the following to your *wrap()*

```
$('#<%= ReportViewer1.ClientID %>').wrap('<div style="overflow:auto; position:relative;" />');
```

The final output should look something like this:

```
<div style="width:500px; overflow:auto; border:solid 1px Black;height:400px; position:relative;">
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="scManager" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Height="400px"  Width="500px"
        SizeToReportContent="true" ZoomMode="Percent" AsyncRendering="false" >
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks so much, saved me from hours of pulling out my hair!

Comment: This also appears to impact IE8 if you're running in backward compatible mode